# PHPExcel excel2007 php output with charts

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use latest `PHPExcel` library for creating `.xls`, `.xlsx` files. When i try to output created file like this:

```
ob_end_clean();

$file = 'test.xls';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

$objPHPWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objPHPWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

everything is fine until I try to create and output any `charts`. So i changed my code according to example:

```
ob_end_clean();

$objPHPWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objPHPWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
exit;
```

This is working, but the file is not downloaded. So i modified code to output created file:

```
ob_end_clean();

$file = 'test.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

$objPHPWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objPHPWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

And this is not working, ends up with ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

Also when i store `excel` file with charts with second code block, it's not compatibile with `MS Excel 2016`. It says the file is corrupted and the data were replaced or deleted. What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `And this is not working.` Which means what exactly? It displays error mesages? It creates a corrupt file? It makes the server eat your pet hamster?

Comment: The Excel5 Writer doesn't support charts, so your first example will not include any charts at all

Comment: If you manually download ad open the file with MS Excel in your second example, what happens?

Comment: @MarkBaker The error is ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. In second example as i wrote it works well. When i download the file everything is ok in OpenOffice, Excel 2007,2010 but Excel 2016 displays error that says something is wrong with your data... and the charts are missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one simple solution, first step is to store created `.xlsx` file, second is to download file with `header("Location:")`. Redundant files are deleted with `array_map` function.

```
array_map('unlink', glob( __DIR__."/*.xlsx"));

$file = 'test.xlsx';
$objPHPWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objPHPWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPWriter->save($file);
header("Location: $file");
```